# Rails 4 Capistrano deployment cannot find activesupport

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am trying to deploy from my local machine to my deployment server via Capistrano. When I deploy, it connects to the server then dumps out the following information.

```
** sftp upload /var/folders/x0/hyzt7pms0599ymtyjft739kw0000gn/T/20160406223514.tar.gz -> /tmp/20160406223514.tar.gz
    [address] /tmp/20160406223514.tar.gz
    [address] done
  * sftp upload complete
  * executing "cd /var/www/address/releases && tar xzf /tmp/20160406223514.tar.gz && rm /tmp/20160406223514.tar.gz"
    servers: ["address"]
    [address] executing command
    command finished in 519ms
  * 2016-04-06 18:35:59 executing `deploy:finalize_update'
    triggering before callbacks for `deploy:finalize_update'
  * 2016-04-06 18:35:59 executing `deploy:assets:symlink'
  * executing "rm -rf /var/www/address/releases/20160406223514/public/assets && mkdir -p /var/www/address/releases/20160406223514/public && mkdir -p /var/www/address/shared/assets && ln -s /var/www/address/shared/assets /var/www/address/releases/20160406223514/public/assets"
    servers: ["server"]
    [server] executing command
    command finished in 48ms
  * executing "chmod -R -- g+w /var/www/address/releases/20160406223514 && rm -rf -- /var/www/address/releases/20160406223514/public/system && mkdir -p -- /var/www/address/releases/20160406223514/public/ && ln -s -- /var/www/address/shared/system /var/www/address/releases/20160406223514/public/system && rm -rf -- /var/www/address/releases/20160406223514/log && ln -s -- /var/www/address/shared/log /var/www/address/releases/20160406223514/log && rm -rf -- /var/www/address/releases/20160406223514/tmp/pids && mkdir -p -- /var/www/address/releases/20160406223514/tmp/ && ln -s -- /var/www/address/shared/pids /var/www/address/releases/20160406223514/tmp/pids"
    servers: ["address"]
    [address] executing command
    command finished in 49ms
    triggering after callbacks for `deploy:update_code'
  * 2016-04-06 18:35:59 executing `deploy:assets:precompile'
    triggering before callbacks for `deploy:assets:precompile'
  * 2016-04-06 18:35:59 executing `deploy:assets:update_asset_mtimes'
  * executing "[ -e '/var/www/address/shared/assets/.sprockets-manifest*' ] && cat /var/www/address/shared/assets/.sprockets-manifest* || echo"
    servers: ["address"]
    [server] executing command
    command finished in 31ms
  * executing "cd -- /var/www/address/releases/20160406223514 && RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets rake assets:precompile"
    servers: ["address"]
    [address] executing command
 ** [out :: address] Could not find activesupport-4.2.0 in any of the sources
 ** [out :: address] Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
    command finished in 547ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /var/www/address/releases/20160406223514; true"
    servers: ["address"]
    [address] executing command
    command finished in 57ms
failed: "sh -c 'cd -- /var/www/address/releases/20160406223514 && RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets rake assets:precompile'" on address
```

It says that it could not find activesupport, but when I run gem list on the server, it is listed and shows version 4.2.6, 4.2.4, 4.2.0.

This is a permissions problem?

Here is deploy.rb

```
set :application, "app"
set :repository,  "repo"

set :deploy_to, '/var/www/address'
set :scm, :git
set :branch, "master"

set :user, "user"

set :use_sudo, false

set :rails_env, "production"
set :deploy_via, :copy

set :keep_releases, 5

default_run_options[:pty] = true

server "address", :app, :web, :db, :primary => true


namespace :deploy do
    desc "Symlink shared config files"
    task :symlink_config_files do
        run "#{ try_sudo } ln -s #{ deploy_to }/shared/config/database.yml #{ current_path }/config/database.yml"
    end

    desc "Restart Passenger app"
    task :restart do
        run "#{ try_sudo } touch #{ File.join(current_path, 'tmp', 'restart.txt') }"
    end
end


after "deploy", "deploy:symlink_config_files"
after "deploy", "deploy:restart"
after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you don't seem to launch a `bundle install` in your capistrano script before trying to do the assets precompilation.

Run a bundle install beforehand and it should work fine.

EDIT: `require 'capistrano/rails'` (or `require 'capistrano/bundler'`) inside of your `Capfile`.

source: https://github.com/capistrano/rails

Comment: This is my first deployment to this server. I will add the code from my deploy.rb to the post above. Should the 'bundle install' be in that file? I am not sure how to run a bundle install on the server before anything get over there. Can you tell me more please?

Comment: I am running Capistrano 2.15.7 and this require does not work. Is there a way to do this with the older version?

Comment: In your `deploy.rb`, add this require: `require 'bundler/capistrano'`. Source: http://bundler.io/v1.3/deploying.html

Comment: Thanks, that got me further, now I am running into a new problem.